# How does a pointer to a constant integer number in C?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I try use a pointer to a constant integer number in C:

```
void *p = NULL;
p = (int *) 1;
printf("p=%d\n", *(int *)p);
```

but I got a segment fault.....

I cannot figure out how a pointer to a constant number in C w/o declaring a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not taking the pointer to a constant but you are converting the constant to a pointer.  You should do something like:

```
const int one = 1;
const int *p;
p = &one;
```

You cannot however do something like:

```
p = &1;
```

since literal constants haven't a memory location.

Comment: I got it. I must declare a const variable to create a memory space which that pointer could point to. Am I right ??

Answer (score 1):

```
 *(int *)p
```

You are derefrencing `p`, which is a pointer that has a value of `1`. It's unlikely to be a valid address, segmentation fault is not a surprise.

P.S: `p` is not a pointer to `const` integer, it has a value of a constant integer.

Comment: @Yun-LungLee It's an invalid address, you can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

`p = (int *) 1;` does not set the pointer `p` to point to a memory location with value `1`. This sets the value of the pointer to 1, i.e, sets the pointer to point to the memory location with address `1`.

Comment: Thanks. You give my another thought.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
void *p = NULL;
const int num = 1;
p = (int*)(&num);
printf("p=%d\n", *((int *)p));
```

Comment: It seems not allowed a pointer directly points to a constant. Thanks.

Comment: you are correct: this change is needed p = (int*)(&num);